# A ddl mismatch issue after upgrading Azure Function app to Dotnet 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I've just upgraded an Azure function app from Dot Net Core v3.1 to Dot Net v6, including updating all the NuGet packages.

The solution compiles but when I run it I'm getting this error:

```
error CS1705: Assembly 'xxxxx' with identity 'xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.33.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than 
referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host' 
with identity 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I can't see any mismatched versions or dependencies. I've cleared the NuGet cache, I've deleted the bin directories and rebuilt.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Probably, when you're upgrading the Azure Functions project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6, you'll get this error. To fix this, you need to change the Azure Functions version to v4 in the `.csproj` file.

Also, Azure Functions Core Tools version 4 should be installed in the System to use Azure Functions .NET 6.

**In a nutshell, some dependencies loaded in memory by Azure Functions SDK, so your libraries will be unable to use newer versions of the same libraries**.

**Few other steps were**:

- Check your NuGet Package Manager that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` is having the correct version according to target framework given in this [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages#languages-by-runtime-version).
- Make Sure all the `dll's` are compiled against the correct versions.
- Regarding the CS1705 error in .NET C#, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1705) for more information like what would be the causes and fixes to this error - provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Installing the Azure Functions Core Tools got me past that error. On to the next one 